# Cannot get the original markdown value from database

Tags: laravel, parsing, markdown

I'm building a forum using Laravel, where I give my users the ability to use markdown to write replies or threads.
Now when the user shares a discussion or reply, later if that user want to edit that reply or discussion I send a request to the database to fetch the original value of reply markdown as shown in the image bellow
[image]

The problem is where the request comes, I get the parsed value in HTML like below:
[image]

When I debug the code inside the controller I found that Laravel parse it before send it to the browser
[image]

and here's the original value from the database:
[image]

Please If someone could tell me how could I prevent Laravel or eloquent from parsing the value in the database.
BTW, I'm using simple (codemirror) for markdown editor

Comment: not sure why anything would be parsing a value from the database like that ... the only thing i could see give you a different value would be an accessor but shouldn't show in the 'original' array different

Answer (score 1):

use this function

```
htmlspecialchars_decode( stripslashes( $variable_name ) )
```

use it where you load value from your database into input field